# Mozilla Public License for core open source modules but proprietary modules?

Tags: license-recommendation, proprietary-code, mpl

I have built a framework that has the core modules: module1, module2, module3, module4.

But I have also build module5 that uses the core modules and also derives classes from the module1. I want module5 to make it proprietary and sell it as binaries and keep the the ownership of the code for module5.
The rest of the 4 core modules can be open source.

Can this be done with Mozilla Public License? Or is there a better license for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can surely be done with the MPL license. At a high level, the MPL is a weak, limited copyleft where the copyleft applies on a per-file basis.

The specific section that would allow your use case is "[3.3. Distribution of a Larger Work](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/#distribution-of-a-larger-work)":

> You may create and distribute a Larger Work under terms of Your choice, provided that You also comply with the requirements of this License for the Covered Software.